# Elasticsearch condensed shards?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I am running a single node (15GB RAM, half allocated on the heap) with ES (1.2.1) and had allocated two indexes with 16 shards a piece with no replicas. Health always reported my "cluster" in the yellow due to a lack of replicas, but aside from that, all was well until this morning.

In total, I am hovering around 65M documents and when I checked the status of ES this morning, it was still yellow, only I now had 5 shards per index. All the documents appear to be in place (counts are still the same in marvel, queries return proper totals), but how did my shard allocation change?

I had chosen 16 shards to allow for simple routing based on document IDs therefore balancing out each shard for when I planned to upgrade nodes. Despite having my data, it appears that the shards are now completely unbalanced. I took a look in the logs when marvel showed the change, but nothing appears to be reported.

I should also mention, shard allocation shows 5 shards per index as "unassigned". What's strange about these unassigned shards is that their shard numbers match the currently active and assigned shards and still do not add up to 16 total. When trying to assign the shards back to the proper node, I get an error saying that the shard has already been attached to that node or that the shard I specified does not exist.

Did ES decide to just consolidate my allocations? Is there a way to get this back? I can't re-assign the "old" shards to a node because there is no indication they ever existing (nothing on disk and settings says 5 shards) and ES tells you to over-allocate to start because you can't add shards later.

Comment: you cannot change the number of shards per index post index creation - and 5 primary shards per index is the default. Are you sure you original index creation successfully changed it from the default?

Comment: The line was included in the creation. Just re-created under a new name and got the settings. It showed the proper 16 shards.